# .htaccess send headers if homepage requested

Tags: .htaccess, cache-control

I am using plain domain name url to display homepage and within htaccess I have

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, private, must-revalidate"
 </FilesMatch>
```

to send Cache-Control header for html files. Unfortunatelly when just the domein is requested the FilesMatch obviously does not match, but I need to send the cache header anyway. ExpiresByType is not a solution as some files of type text/html are needed to keep uncached (forexample php script sending text/html data). Sending header by PHP is also not an option as the homepage html is cached in filesystem and served by apache directly (htaccess rule) without touching php. I am sure there must be some easy solution, but not able to figure out right now..thanks for help

Comment: What Apache version are you using? With 2.4, you could probably use expressions for that, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples I’m guessing something like `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/'">` or similar should work.

Comment: Apache 2.4, ended up with the same conclusion, however was not able to make it work as expected..will have to dive into it again with a fresh mind today..